# Converting an array to a two dimensional

Tags: php, arrays, csv

The further I get in the code, the more I feel like I am going about this all wrong.

I have an array with some key/values and some nested arrays also. It looks something like below:

```
Array
(
    [key1] => valueA
    [key2] => valueB
    [key3] => valueC
    [key4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [key1] => value1
                [key2] => value2
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [key1] => value3
                [key2] => value4
            )
    )
    [key5] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [key1] => value5
                [key2] => value6
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [key1] => value7
                [key2] => value8
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [key1] => value9
                [key2] => value10
            )
    )
)
```

My goal is to output this array (the quickest and easiest way) as CSV format.

So outputting this array in that format would look like:

```
Column 1, Column 2, Column 3, Column 4, Column 5, Column 6, Column 7
valueA, valueB, valueC, value1, value2, value5, value6
null,   null,   null,   value3, value4, value7, value8,
null,   null,   null,   null,   null,   value9, value10
```

One way I thought to do this would be to make the array into a two dimensional (even though it technically is), by filling the extra places with nulls.

**Is there a way to convert that array quickly in PHP? or similiar?**

Comment: Why not iterate through and check whether the current value is an array or a string? php has a built in `is_array()` function. Basically loop through, if its an array do another loop for that value, if its not then just output that value into your proper format. With that said it is kind of difficult to understand what is going on with the arbitrary values in your example.

Comment: Are the array lengths (column count) static? Or can key 4 have 3 rows instead of 2? If they are not static then you need a different approach. Looks like you are trying to convert a multi-dimensional array to a 2D array - this is not easy with variable data rows. If it is static then your proposed method should work.

Comment: I do currently use is_array(). The issue is that the key4 could have 0+  arrays in it. And same with key5. So it is static that key4 will always be an array, but not that it has the same number of arrays in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My method could have been written much simpler if I knew which aspects of your input were static.  For instance, will there always be 7 columns?  Will the non-arrays always come before the arrays?  In the absense of this knowledge, I have produced an approach that should be sufficiently flexible.  ...Is it quick and easy?  IMO, no.

Input:

```
$input=[
        'key1'=>'valueA',
        'key2'=>'valueB',
        'key3'=>'valueC',
        'key4'=>[
            ['key1'=>'value1','key2'=>'value2'],
            ['key1'=>'value3','key2'=>'value4']
         ],
        'key5'=>[
            ['key1'=>'value5','key2'=>'value6'],
            ['key1'=>'value7','key2'=>'value8'],
            ['key1'=>'value9','key2'=>'value10']
         ]
       ];
```

Method ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4ad33d0dab04fdef98a91f0bebc0289b03593afe)):

```
$col=0;
foreach(array_values($input) as $k1=>$v1){
    if(!is_array($v1)){
        if(!isset($result[0])){$result[0]=[];}
        $result[0][$col]=$v1;
        ++$col;             // shift attention to next allowable column
    }else{
        foreach($v1 as $k2=>$v2){
            foreach(array_values($v2) as $k3=>$v3){
                if(!isset($result[$k2])){$result[$k2]=[];}
                $result[$k2][$col+$k3]=$v3;
            }
        }
        $col+=sizeof($v2);  // shift attention to next allowable column
    }
}

for($x=0,$count=sizeof($result[0]); $x<$count; ++$x){
    $colheads[]='Column '.($x+1);                             // build column headings
    foreach($result as $i=>$a){
        if(!isset($result[$i][$x])){$result[$i][$x]=null;}    // null fill
    }
}

foreach($result as &$a){
    ksort($a);                     // sort each subarray using keys (put nulls in order)
}
array_unshift($result,$colheads);  // attach column heads to the start of result array
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
[
    ['Column 1','Column 2','Column 3','Column 4','Column 5','Column 6','Column 7'],
    ['valueA','valueB','valueC','value1','value2','value5','value6'],
    [NULL,NULL,NULL,'value3','value4','value7','value8'],
    [NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'value9','value10']
]
```

Comment: This looks like it would be a great solution. However they will not be static. But most likely there will never be more than a certain amount of rows. So would it be a bad idea to basically fill the output with 10 rows of null, then wipe what does not get filled with anything else? That would make my output "static" in a sense

Comment: @blapaz Do you have another sample input where my answer fails?  I am happy to adjust anything that isn't quite right.

Comment: I ended up doing this a bit different, but following the idea of your code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){

    if($i==3){
        $separator=';'.PHP_EOL;
    }else{ 
        $separator=',';
    }
    $tab[]=$array["key$i"].$separator;
}
for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){
    if($i==2){
        $separator=';'.PHP_EOL;
    }else{ 
        $separator=',';
    }
    $tab2[]=$array["key4"][0]["key$i"].$separator;
}

for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){
    if($i==2){
        $separator=';'.PHP_EOL;
    }else{ 
        $separator=',';
    }
    $tab3[]=$array["key4"][1]["key$i"].$separator;
}

 for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){
     if($i==2){
        $separator=';'.PHP_EOL;
    }else{ 
        $separator=',';
    }
    $tab4[]=$array["key5"][0]["key$i"].$separator;
}
 for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){

      if($i==2){
        $separator=';'.PHP_EOL;
    }else{ 
        $separator=',';
    }

    $tab5[]=$array["key5"][1]["key$i"].$separator;
}
 for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){

      if($i==2){
        $separator=';'.PHP_EOL;
    }else{ 
        $separator=',';
    }

    $tab6[]=$array["key5"][2]["key$i"].$separator;
}


$handle = fopen('blapaz.csv','w');



foreach($tab as $output) { 

    fwrite($handle,$output);
}

foreach($tab2 as $output) { 

    fwrite($handle,$output);
}
foreach($tab3 as $output) { 
      fwrite($handle,$output);

}
foreach($tab4 as $output) { 

    fwrite($handle,$output);
}
foreach($tab5 as $output) { 

    fwrite($handle,$output);
}

foreach($tab6 as $output) { 

    fwrite($handle,$output);
}


?>
```

You want change from array to multidimensional, whether from multidemnsional to string?

```
$array = array(

'key1' => 'valueA',
'key2' => 'valueB',
'key3' => 'valueC',
'key4' => 
[0=>    [
        'key1'=>'value1',
        'key2'=>'value2',
        ],
        ['key1'=>'value3',
        'key2'=>'value4',
        ]       
],
'key5' => [
            0 => [
            'key1'=>'value5',
            'key2'=>'value6',
            ],
            1 => [
            'key1'=>'value7',
            'key2'=>'value8',
            ],
            2 => [
            'key1'=>'value9',
            'key2'=>'value10',
            ],


]

);
```

This??

```
$handle = fopen('blapaz.csv','w');

for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){


     $tab[]=$array["key$i"].',';

}




for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){

    $tab2[]=$array["key4"][0]["key$i"].',' ;
}

for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){

    $tab3[]=$array["key4"][1]["key$i"].',' ;
}

 for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){

    $tab4[]=$array["key5"][0]["key$i"].',' ;
}
 for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){



    $tab5[]=$array["key5"][1]["key$i"].',' ;
}
 for($i=1;$i<=2;$i++){


    $tab6[]=$array["key5"][2]["key$i"].',' ;
}



 $zmienna[] =  $tab[0].$tab[1].$tab[2].$tab2[0].$tab2[1].$tab4[0].$tab4[1].PHP_EOL.
 ','.','.','.$tab3[0].$tab3[1].$tab5[0].$tab5[1].PHP_EOL.
 ','.','.','.','.','.$tab6[0].$tab6[1];

 fputcsv($handle,$zmienna);
//print_r(str_getcsv($zmienna));

$handle = fopen('blapaz.csv','r');
print_r(  fgetcsv($handle));

?>
```